# How to play a video from a particular timestamp when user clicks on a button in Brightcove

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, brightcove, react-player

I am working on Brightcove to play a video. I need to play a video from a particular timestamp within the video. For eg: if the user clicks on a button the video should play from  5 min 30 sec of the video. I think the idea is clear. I am using brightcove/react-player-loader to play video.

```
<ReactPlayerLoader
    onSuccess={onVideoSuccess}
    accountId={accountID}
    videoId={mediaID}
    playerId={playerID}
    attrs={{ className: "brightcove", autoPlay: "muted" }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { useRef } from 'react'
const mediaRef = useRef()

const gotoTimeStamp = (time) => {
    mediaRef.current.player.currentTime(time)
  }


return ( 

 <ReactPlayerLoader
   ref={mediaRef}
    onSuccess={onVideoSuccess}
    accountId={accountID}
    videoId={mediaID}
    playerId={playerID}
   attrs={{ className: 'brightcove', autoPlay: 'muted />


 <button onClick={() => gotoTimeStamp(1434)}>
   Click me            
  </button>
)
```

Comment: Hey @Happy bean do you have any idea about the brightcove sdk - android. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72441285/brightcove-video-player-not-playing-drm-enabled-videos-in-android