# Brightcove video player not playing DRM enabled videos in Android

Tags: android, video, drm, brightcove

I am trying to play videos(DRM enalbed) in brightcove video player.
What I did so far is. also I have extend the class with `BrightcovePlayer`

```
    // Get the event emitter from the SDK
    EventEmitter eventEmitter = brightcoveVideoView.getEventEmitter();
    // Create a catalog request to fetch a video
    String account = getString(R.string.account);
    Catalog catalog = new Catalog.Builder(eventEmitter, account)
            .setBaseURL(Catalog.DEFAULT_EDGE_BASE_URL)
            .setPolicy(getString(R.string.policy))
            .build();

    // Get the video by ID
    catalog.findVideoByID(getString(R.string.videoId), new VideoListener() {

        @Override
        public void onVideo(Video video) {
            // Add video to the view
            brightcoveVideoView.add(video);
            // Start video playback
            brightcoveVideoView.start();
        }
    });
```

XML layout is

```
 <com.brightcove.player.view.BrightcoveExoPlayerVideoView
        android:id="@+id/brightcove_video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"/>
```

This is just showing video controls only not playing the videos

Comment: There's a complete example at https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/android-player-samples/blob/master/brightcove-exoplayer/WidevineModularSampleApp/src/main/java/com/brightcove/player/samples/exoplayer/widevine/MainActivity.java

Comment: @misterben this is just for normal video playback. I want to play DRM enabled video. Do you have any reference?

Answer (score 0):

Brightcove recommend using ExoPlayer for Widevine DRM protected content - on Android you will most likely be using Widevine DRM as it is the native DRM for Android.

> To view Widevine Modular content, you need to use the ExoPlayer video view

(https://sdks.support.brightcove.com/features/content-security-drm-native-player-sdks.html)

The link above includes a link to a sample: https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/android-player-samples/tree/master/brightcove-exoplayer/WidevineModularSampleApp/src/main